# SQL statement to convert dd/mm/yy nvarchar(255) to Date format dd/mm/yyyy

Tags: sql, sql-server, date-conversion

I am struggling with a SQL statement to convert imported data that is in a format `dd/mm/yy` and of type `nvarchar(255)` into a `date` type 'dd/mm/yyyy' format.

The sample data is as follows:

Date:

```
'23/10/17'
'24/10/17'
'25/10/17'
'26/10/17'
'27/10/17'
```

To Date Format:

```
'23/10/2017'
'24/10/2017'
'25/10/2017'
'26/10/2017'
'27/10/2017'
```

I am using SQL Server 2008 R2

Comment: Please be more specific with your question, do you want a date format with dd/mm/yy?

Comment: use `CONVERT( datetime, imported_date_col, 103)` for `dd/mm/yyyy` or `CONVERT( datetime, imported_date_col, 3)` for `dd/mm/yy`

Comment: basically your first issue is how to determine what century a 2 digit year is in. The Y2K problem.  If the date is 26/11/16 would that be 1916 or 2016???  once you identify that do some string manipulation to convert the yy to yyyy then you can cast/convert as desired but without that rule nothing we write will be correct

Answer (score 3):

Here you go:

```
WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT '23/10/17' AS MyDate
    UNION
    SELECT '24/10/17'
    UNION
    SELECT '25/10/17'
    UNION
    SELECT '26/10/17'
    UNION
    SELECT '27/10/17'
    )
    SELECT * , 
          CONVERT(DATE, MyDate,3) AS MyDate, 
          CONVERT(VARCHAR, CONVERT(DATE, MyDate,3), 103) AS ExactFormat
    FROM CTE;
```

Results:

```
+----------+---------------------+-------------+
|  MyDate  |       MyDate        | ExactFormat |
+----------+---------------------+-------------+
| 23/10/17 | 23.10.2017 00:00:00 | 23/10/2017  |
| 24/10/17 | 24.10.2017 00:00:00 | 24/10/2017  |
| 25/10/17 | 25.10.2017 00:00:00 | 25/10/2017  |
| 26/10/17 | 26.10.2017 00:00:00 | 26/10/2017  |
| 27/10/17 | 27.10.2017 00:00:00 | 27/10/2017  |
+----------+---------------------+-------------+
```

**[Demo](http://rextester.com/AHUB95968)**

Answer (score 2):

Try using CONVERT.

```
SELECT convert(datetime, datecolumn, 103);
```

Refer these links for more detail

http://www.sqlusa.com/bestpractices/datetimeconversion/

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql

Hope this helps.

Comment: @Matt: for a 2-digit year (bad idea!), you can use style "3" instead of "103" - see the docs

Comment: @marc_s DUHH but the OP is asking how to convert a 2 digit year to a 3 digit `SQL statement to convert dd/mm/yy nvarchar(255) to Date format dd/mm/yyy` and this answer doesn't do that

Comment: @Matt: I very much assume that the "three-digit" year is just a typo and should be *four* digits....

Comment: @marc_s so do I which is why I had commented 4 originally....clearly my comment in its original form must have been not well formed.  so hopefully my other comment and this one which says the OP is asking how to convert a 2 digit year in a string to a DATETIME.  And this answer doesn't do that will afford visitors not to use this solution and prompt poster to remove the answer or change to be correct.

Comment: Thank you for your responses i edited the typo it is yyyy apologies.

Answer (score -1):

USE REPLACE

CONVERT(DATE,REPLACE('23/10/17', '/17', '/2017'))

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).